# Number formatting a function value (currency)

Tags: php, wordpress, formatting, currency

I am using the Advanced Custom Fields wordpress plugin and I am outputting the value of one of the fields:   `the_field('Price');` which gives a number .

I want to format this number as pounds sterling with commas.

I am having some problems outputting it. It seems to be to do with which comes first the outputted function value or the number format function.

```
$money = the_field('Price');
echo  '&pound;' . number_format($money,0, '.', '');
```

This doesn't work and outputs e.g. `300000£0`

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `the_field()` doesn't return anything but echoes instead.

You can write your own custom function:

```
function my_the_field($field, $post_id = false) {
    $value = get_field($field_name, $post_id);
    if (is_array($value)) {
        $value = @implode(', ', $value);
    }
    return $value;
}
```

and use that in place of `the_field()`

or capture output using `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()` and pass it to `number_format()`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the excellent answer:

the second option worked:

ob_start();

```
        the_field('Price');

        $out = ob_get_clean();
        $out = strtolower($out);

       echo '&pound;' .  number_format($out);

       // var_dump($out);
```

Answer (score 0):

@Andrew Welch
Your solution works but the function already exists in ACF (Advanced Custom Fields)

```
if (get_field('Price')){
 the_field('Price');
}
```